# Nginx: proxy_pass cannot have URI part in location inside "if" statement

Tags: nginx

Suppose there's a nginx configuration:

```
server {
    ...
    location /nakayoshi {
        if ($georedirect) {
            proxy_pass http://foo.bar/fa/fb/fc;
        }
        proxy_pass http://foo.bar/fa/fb/fd;
    }
}
```

When I `sudo nginx -t`, it prints out:

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular express, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nakayoshi.conf
```

Also I've found `rewrite` help me here, but the redirected uri will change to urls like "http://foo.bar/fa/fb/fc".

Can I keep the redirected uris unchanged with `proxy_pass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
http {
    ...
    map $georedirect $proxyuri {
        "" fa/fb/fd;
        default fa/fb/fc;
    }
    server {
        ...
        location /nakayoshi {
            proxy_pass http://foo.bar/$proxyuri;
        }
    }
}
```